# Why does live server browser opens up with code written on one side of screen

Tags: browser, formatting, liveserver

I am currently taking classes in react and I use VS Code to write my code.When I write my code and style it then open the live server from vscode,it opens up in a browser but not centered on the screen, everything is blocked to the left side of the browser, like I am working with one side of the screen.I thought it was the formatting in vscode so i uninstalled and reinstalled but nothing.I reset the browser setting to default still nothing as seen

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

When you open the live server close the window opens by vs code. And go to the browser and type the server address with the number of port.